# windows service setup installer

Tags: c#, windows-services, setup-project

I am trying to have setup installer for my windows service, but i am getting this error

```
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  
HRESULT = '80070057' ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '80070057'
  ------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup2' completed ------
  ------ Pre-build validation for project 'Setup2' completed ------ 
2>------ Build started: Project: Setup2, Configuration: Debug ------ 
2>------ Build started: Project: Setup2, Configuration: Debug ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I followed this post, but still getting same error.
[How to create an installer for a .net Windows Service using Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021075/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-net-windows-service-using-visual-studio)

Any help?

Thanks,
Kristijan.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838452/error-an-error-occurred-while-validating-hresult-80070057  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337529/cannot-build-visual-studio-installer-project-when-main-project-has-any-winmd-re

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this process to solve issue       https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-windows-services-in-c-sharp/?

Comment: i could install with installutil in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, but trying to have setup with wizard to install it. Sorry,this does not solve my problem. Thanks.